# Xterm.js weird behaviour in macOs

Tags: xtermjs

I've implemented `Xterm` in `react` project.
while I look on mac I see that letter spacing is weird looking. However on a `windows` machine it look perfectly fine.

I use default letter spacing in code.

[image: Weird behaviour on MacOS]

Could somebody please help me about this issue?

[image: Expected behaviour in Windows]

Comment: Hi Raj, how did you get xterm set up to work as an actual terminal? The docs are lacking...

Comment: first you should create xterm server for communication to the console. then create ui. there is server example in xtermjs repo